# SQL sequential number failure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some code that takes the users id and last modified date to create a sequence that needs to be incremental. This isn't always the case so the update that should be happening off of this script doesn't always work.

```
DECLARE @SequenceNumber BIGINT
SET @SequenceNumber = 0

SELECT  
    [Student_ID] as IDCode,
    [Last_modified] as LastModified,
    CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Last_modified] AS FLOAT)) AS BIGINT) * 1000000 + DATEPART(hour, [Last_modified]) * 10000 + DATEPART(minute, [Last_modified]) * 100 + DATEPART(second,[Last_modified])) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), RIGHT('00000' + RTRIM([Student_ID]), 5))) AS SequenceNumber
FROM 
    [CardDB].[dbo].[Card]
WHERE
    convert(bigint,convert(varchar(max),cast(floor(cast([Last_modified] as float)) as bigint)*1000000 + DATEPART(hour,[Last_modified]) * 10000 + DATEPART(minute,[Last_modified]) * 100 + DATEPART(second,[Last_modified]))+convert(varchar(max), RIGHT('00000'+ rtrim([Student_ID]),5))) > @SequenceNumber
ORDER by 
    SequenceNumber ASC
```

The bug is the way I am creating the sequence number. We need to use the last modified date to know which record to update but adding the id to this does not always create a larger number. So what I see sometimes are updates with a lower sequence number and the last sequence number is stored in a config file and this is what the program is using to know where to start from each time it runs.

Example sequence numbers

```
4246610134504882  
4246610134504827  
4246610134504805  
4246610134504406   **  
4246610134503828   **
4246610134502560   **
4246610134502402   **
4246610134502383   **
4246610134504422
```

The number in bold would get missed being updated.

Comment: You could add `rowversion` column: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Comment: im thinking of going with row_number()

Comment: I don't think that's what you want - `row_number()` just assigns a sequential number to each row of a result-set. If you update a field that's not in the order by, you won't get a new number for the row. If anything changes the order of your records (an insert in the middle for example), all your numbers will change.

Comment: more along the lines of adding row_number() to the last_modified date. Its a select query that needs a unique sequential number. an update will have a different number, thats fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- convert LastModified to varbinary
- then to varchar
- extract days and ticks portion with substring() or Left/Right. We need it to change the order of days/ticks as ticks go first, then days.
- then convert hex varchar value (days + ticks) to bigint
- multiply by N (where N is maximum possible Student ID)  (to handle scenarios where multiple records have same timestamp)
- finally add StudentID. Such number will be unique and sequential

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/12/15/the-internal-storage-of-a-datetime2-value.aspx